# read images using opencv inside tensorflow data loader

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

how to use opencv to read images and augument data for a tensoflow data loader, the filepath comming from tensorflow data loader is not string

```
self.original_image = cv2.imread(input_path)
```

`TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'`

```
class augmentImage:
  def __init__(self, height, width) -> None:
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.orignial_image = None
    self.target = None
    self.source = None
 
  def __call__(self,image_file ):
    self.augment(image_file)

  def augment(self,input_path):
      # Read the image
      self.original_image = cv2.imread(input_path)
      self.image =  self.original_image.copy()
      return tf.cast(cv2.cvtColor(self.image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), tf.float32)
```

```
agumentation = augmentImage(256, 256)

def load_image_train(image_file):
  input_image, real_image = agumentation(image_file)
  input_image, real_image = normalize(input_image, real_image)
  return input_image, real_image

img_list = glob.glob('/content/data/dataset_pix2pix/train/*.jpg')
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_list)#(str(PATH / 'train/*.jpg'))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_image_train,
                                  num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Comment: HI @Athul Suresh The issue with your code is that TensorFlow's from_tensor_slices method expects a tensor-like object, not a list of file paths. You need to convert the list of file paths to a TensorFlow tensor before using it with from_tensor_slices.